# CI/CD: One dockerfile for all environments or one dockerfile per environment

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, containers, continuous-deployment

I have `dev` / `test` / `preprod` / `prod` environments with GitLab CI/CD. According to best practices, should I :

- Have one dockerfile **per** environment ?
- Have one dockerfile **for all** environments ?

Firstly, I thought having one unique provisioning for all the environments was the strength of containers. But in my case, with my angular application, I have **a lot of dev dependencies** (such as virtual browsers) for testing purpose that sould not be in the `prod` environment.

How should I organize my containers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create one base image and upload it to my registry. It has minimal core software that should be on production.

For development and testing purposes i create different Dockerfiles based on base image.

For example, for resting purposes i install test framework on base image and for development purposes i change user and group id of the user inside the base image. (so when i bind mount i won't have permission problem in my local)

For CI purposes i do the same.

When i want to push to production i take base image + artifact from CI + config for production and bundle them in production image.

Long story short, one base image (Dockerfile) and different Dockerfile(s) for each contex based on base image.

With this setup i can be sure that i will have same version core software on all environments.